# How to create a connectionString into a online database

Tags: c#, wpf, connection-string

I'm trying to make a login app.

I would like to know how the connectionString on app.config is made for an online connection and if I would need anything else to reach the database, being as I'm trying to go directly to the user table on that database and perform a check for the login (as I already made it happen with a local database)

Best Regards

Comment: Please show your code, explain what the problem is with it.

Comment: Connection strings for most databases
http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 1):

Your online database, does that mean a database at a remote location?

I would advise against going directly to a remote database unless that database server is protected in a LAN environment with no outside public access. Public access would also be considered if users inside the LAN also have unregulated access to the remote server. In any thick click based application the typical architecture would be to go through a proxy source or set of `WebServices` to authorize and authenticate users. Direct access opens your SQL server up to remote attacks.

That being said the connection string to an SQL server (remotely) could be:

**Standard User\Pass**

```
Server=myRemoteServer;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

Now chances are there are firewalls between the remote database and your client APP protecting remote logins (as there should) and it is a good possiblity that SQL server has disabled remote logins. Read here for more http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

I must point out again that this is a very bad idea and I would *personally* create a set of `WCF` WebServices to run on the server with the database. The WCF services would be responsible for connecting to the database to verify the credentials and return a structured datamodel.

WPF Applications are designed to work really well with the `Async` methods of WCF services and are very simple to setup. Using this model you can also setup more advanced layers of authentication using hashed token sets, implement SSL to block `sniffing` out the plain text, and keep your database protected from external access.

There are alot of examples on the web to connect to WCF services from a WPF application.